# Disable Laravel debugger

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel application that was not developed by me. There is some weird bar at the bottom of each page, it is some type of Laravel debugger tool.

I believe it is stored in storage/debugger. Is there a safe way I can go about checking to see if this is actually it and if so can I delete this type of tool without it affecting the application? Does anybody know what this thing is if so any advice on how to remove this safely would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

I had searched online and I had seen most of solution are related to.env file. But I am unable to find.env file in code.

Comment: `.env` is a separate file. If you don't see it, make sure you have checked the setting to show hidden files.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open `.env` file of your laravel project, It is normally located at the root of laravel project.
2. Change `APP_DEBUG` to `false`.
3. If you are not able to file `.env`, Please add your project file structure in your question.
4. To get file structure open the laravel root folder and run this command `tree /F`.

Note : `tree /F` Command only works in windows.

Comment: Thank you but in.env file app   it show  app debug =false and debugger enabled =false. Is there any other option?

Comment: Can you please provide code of .env `Hide app key and other key and secret`

Comment: as said in the answer APP_DEBUG  and DEBUGGER_ENABLED should be false also after changing to false run php artisan config:cache , php artisan cache:clear , php artisan config:clear if it doesnot work also check config/app.php for a debugbar entry to true

Comment: Should I need to change debugger entry true in config/app.php?